# How to pass object between pages in Primefaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, jsf-2.2

In datatable, by clicking datatable element per row, is there a basic solution to pass this clicked object to next page? Which scope annotation is proper for this?

Comment: Pass the object's identifier to the next page in question and construct the object accordingly probably by using a converter. A bean scope is nevertheless, purely requirement-dependent.

Comment: No, session scope is wrong.

Comment: Thank you but problem is solved. f:param and viewscope is used.